# shell_exec() says disabled for security reasons in live server

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, server

I am running a command from php code using `shell_exec()`. In my local environment it is working fine. But while I have deployed my code to the live server it says `shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons`.

I have talk with my server team. They said `shell_exec()` is enabled in my site. I have tried to run those command using putty. Those are working perfect. Like I want to run this command on my php code.
`ffmpeg -i 1.mp3  -vstats 2>&1`. If I run this code using putty its giving me proper result. Isn't it means `shell_exec()` is available in my server ? as I can run it using putty command. But while I try to run this command in php like this `shell_exec(ffmpeg -i 1.mp3  -vstats 2>&1);` it says `shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons`. I have checked `disable_functions` in my `php.ini` file. It is empty. Like this `disable_functions =`.

And one more thing, I am using CakePhp.

Comment: Are you sure you / the admins looked at the correct ini file? To see which file is loaded, create a file with `phpinfo()` in it and look for the loaded ini files (right at the top) and if you find anything about `shell_exec()` or not.

Comment: It is showing `shell_exec` is in disabled. But in `ini` file `disabled_function` is still empty

Comment: Which version of php do you use?

Comment: @TobiasF. php 5.6.39

Comment: Do you have access to the server via a shell? If so, then try a `cat /path/to/php.ini | grep shell_exec`.

Comment: What this command will do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187181/discussion-between-tobias-f-and-fokrule).

Comment: The ini file used by your command line PHP is not necessarily the same as the one used by Apache.

Comment: Solved by taking help from my server team. My created php.ini was not loading.